# Splitting one XML-file into multiple files with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm struggling to split my XML file in multiple XML-files. I need all elements and attributes from the -element with the same status_ids in a seperate file with the *status_id* as the filename.

The XML-File looks somewhat like:

```
<some>
    <more status="1" att="q" status_id="111">
        <text>asdf</text>
    </more>
    <more status="2" att="c" status_id="111">
        <text>fdas</text>
    </more>
    <more status="2" att="a" status_id="111">
        <text>qwer</text>
    </more>

    <more status="1" att="w" status_id="222">
        <text>yxcv</text>
    </more>
    <more status="2" att="f" status_id="222">
        <text>vvbmn</text>
    </more>
    <more status="2" att="g" status_id="222">
        <text>fgjh</text>
    </more>
</some>
```

What I want:
**XML-File_111.xml**

```
<some>
    <more status="1" att="q" status_id="111">
        <text>asdf</text>
    </more>
    <more status="2" att="c" status_id="111">
        <text>fdas</text>
    </more>
    <more status="2" att="a" status_id="111">
        <text>qwer</text>
    </more>
</some>
```

**XML-File_222.xml**

```
<some>
    <more status="1" att="w" status_id="222">
        <text>yxcv</text>
    </more>
    <more status="2" att="f" status_id="222">
        <text>vvbmn</text>
    </more>
    <more status="2" att="g" status_id="222">
        <text>fgjh</text>
    </more>
</some>
```

My XSLT so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">
<xsl:template match="/test">
    <xsl:for-each select="test/some/more">
        <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="file_{@status_id}.xml">
            <root>
                <xsl:copy-of select="//more[type = current()/status_id]/@*"/>
                <elem>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="../@* | ." />
                </elem>
            </root>
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

But I'm not getting anywhere with it. I get only one empty XML-File. So I'm doing something totally wrong, but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typical grouping problem:

```
<xsl:template match="some">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="more" group-by="@status_id">
    <xsl:result-document href="file_{current-grouping-key()}.xml">
       <some>
         <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
       </some>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Working great, thanks! Just a question so I can learn a bit more, was my attempt even remotely feasible?

Comment: Hard to tell, your XSLT shown has `xsl:template match="/test"` and `xsl:for-each select="test/some/more` while your shown XML input does not have any `test` element. And splitting on any `more`, as your attempt with `xsl:for-each select="test/some/more"`  and a nested `xsl:result-document` would do, is not what you said you wanted to do. So you lacked any grouping attempt and the `for-each-group` in XSLT 2 and later makes that easy, whether the incorrect XPath expressions are only part of your question description here on SO or a reason to start with XPath basics is something I can't judge.